# How get parameter from link?

Tags: php, arrays, parameters

I have the link:

> `http://test.com/catalog/?&order_type[input]=1`

I want to get the value parameter `order_type[input]`.

For this I use the following code: `var_dump($_GET["order_type[input]"]);` but this code is not right.

Tell me please how I can get the value parameter `order_type[input]` from this link?

Comment: `$_GET["order_type"]["input"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use like this

```
<?php echo $_GET['order_type']['input']; ?>
```